# Upgade from SQL Server 2012 cluster Evaluation to enterprise

Tags: sql-server-2012

What I understand is that there is a restriction of upgrading a SQL Server 2012 cluster from evaluation edition to licensed standard edition.

Is there a similar limitation for upgrade from cluster evaluation edition to licensed enterprise edition. If no , can you please provide a link for the upgrade process

Answer (score 2):

Supported Upgrade Path for SQL 2012 can be found here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

*Upgrade from SQL Server 2005 Evaluation, SQL Server 2008 Evaluation, and SQL Server 2008 R2 Evaluation to SQL Server 2012 is not supported.*

So if you are just making a 2012 eval edition to a full enterprise edition it'll work.  You can do so by starting setup.exe to bring up the installation menu. 
Go to maintenance, then 'edition upgrade'
See the pic:

[image: screenshot]

Or you could run the command line to install SQL Server but pass in the Product ID, using your own path, /q command optional.

```
setup.exe /q /ACTION=editionupgrade /InstanceName=MSSQLSERVER /PID=<appropriatePid> /SkipRules= Engine_SqlEngineHealthCheck
```